# Coloring of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm 98% colourblind for red/green and blue/yellow.
Im Developing C# in VS2013.

I have a bar wich shows me where errors, warnings or infos are (red, oragne and green) - see the attached picture. However I can barely difference those. How can I change the color of those to lets say white, red and blue?

[image: The bar symbols to change]

Comment: Do you have Resharper or another extension installed? If so, those bars are probably drawn by that extension; check the color for display items starting with "resharper"

Comment: "check the color for display items" is very vague, I searched all resharper settings before but found nothing

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the name of the setting myself, or even whether there is such a setting, otherwise I would have posted an answer.